# How to remove decimal places in the Crystal Report by formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have these number fields:

```
-289444.34000000000   -----> I need this  -289444.34
172231.00000000       -----> I need this   172231.00
```

I am new to CR. I tried this format style "-1123.00" and this: (1123.00) but that is now what I need. I think I need a formula.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way is that "not what you need"?

Comment: This is a value I get from db: 172231.00000000, when I apply -1123.00, I get what I need for positive number, this: 172231.00, but for negative, I get #######, if I choose (1123.00), for negative number I get (#######). And I have a lot of fields. So, is there some kind of formula to solve this?

Comment: As I said, I am new to CR. It works. Thanks. But besides this, those styles are always good, there is no such thing as formula for decimals or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the rounding portion via formula, but you cannot control how the number actually displays via formula without converting it to a string (by using the `totext()` function and passing in a format string).

It's better to just choose a format style for your numeric field so you can continue to do summaries on it, etc. If you choose a format style and it displays "#########" then that means that your field is not big enough to display the number (CR does this to prevent unintentional clipping). You just need to increase the size of your fields.